# How can AWS SES send emails on my behalf after just verifying my email though a link?

Tags: email, security, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES API to send emails to some people. Currently I'm using my personal gmail address as the source.
How exactly does Amazon have permission to send all these email messages on my behalf after just verifying it though a confirmation link?

From my understanding, email service providers will just trust the email if it was sent by AWS SES. Is this the case?

I read the AWS SES documentation. I checked what SMTP is and learned about security measures like SPF, DKIM, and DMARC. But I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you read about SMTP protocol, you understand that SMTP servers use a relay service to send emails between domains, the provider of such service, in this case AWS through SES puts in place some measures to avoid using unverified sender mail addresses as the one you went through.
Then SES is relaying your emails to other domains where this is being processed
I think this SendGrid post it is explained very well "https://sendgrid.com/blog/smtp-relay-service-basics/"